# borrow function from other object in JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var gameController = {
    scores: [20, 34, 55, 46, 77],
    avgScore: 112,
    players: [
        {name: "Ruth", playerId: 100, age: 22},
        {name: "Shawnee", playerId: 101, age: 21}
    ]
};
var appController = {
    scores: [900, 845, 809, 950],
    avgScore: null,
    avg: function () {
        var sumOfScores = this.scores.reduce(function (prev, cur, index, array) {
            return prev + cur;
        });

        this.avgScore = sumOfScores / this.scores.length;
    }
};
gameController.avgScore = appController.avg();
console.log(gameController.avgScore);
```

I tried to borrow the avg method defined in appController to do the calculation for gameController. I understand that after `gameController.avgScore = appController.avg();`, this keyword in avg method will still point to appController as avg method was invoked by appController so I expect avgScore in gameController should remain intact, but the output is undefined, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`avg` doesn't return anything, so it implicitly returns `undefined`. You are basically doing `gameController.avgScore = undefined;`.

If you want to apply the `avg` method to `gameController`, you could use [**`.call`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
appController.avg.call(gameController);
```

Better would probably be to have `avg` as a standalone function that accepts an array of numbers as input (argument) and returns the average.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:** 
When assigning a function to an object the this keyword is set to the object when the function is invoked. This is true only for unbound function references. If the function reference is bound to another object you will have to use the `Function.bind()` method to ensure this is set to the correct object.

**Answer**
Rather than use call each time just assign the function to the object. When the function is call the `this` is set to the object

```
gameController.avg = appController.avg; // unbound function reference.
// now when you need to get the average for gameController 
// just call its avg function
gameController.avg();  // this is automatically set to gameControler
```

Better still create the function outside the controllers and assign them at creation time.

```
// define the avg and refer it to the unbound function that you will share
var avg = function () { 
    var sumOfScores = this.scores.reduce(function (prev, cur, index, array) {
        return prev + cur;
    });
    this.avgScore = sumOfScores / this.scores.length;
    console.log(this.avgScore);
}
// create the objects as normal
var gameController = {
    scores: [20, 34, 55, 46, 77],
    avgScore: 112,
    players: [
        {name: "Ruth", playerId: 100, age: 22},
        {name: "Shawnee", playerId: 101, age: 21}
    ],
    avg:avg  // avg is automatically bound to gameController when it is called
};
var appController = {
    scores: [900, 845, 809, 950],
    avgScore: null,
    avg:avg  // avg is automatically bound to appController when it is called
};
// or if you want to get really lazy. 
var otherController = {
    scores: [900, 900, 900, 900],
    avgScore: null,
    avg  // avg is automatically bound to otherController when it is called
         // and it is automatically named avg as well
};
appController.avg();  // 46.4
gameController.avg(); // 876
otherController.avg(); // 900
```

And there are over half a dozen other ways to achieve the same thing.

Comment: There is no need for bind. `gameController.avg = appController.avg;` woud work as well. *"avg is automatically bound to gameController"* Note that those functions are actually not "bound".

Comment: @Felix Kling You are correct no, need to bind. But MDN suggests they are bound  _"In the following example, when o.f() (as object method) is invoked, inside the function this is bound to the o object."_  
[MDN this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method)  But  I will investigate further and determin the semantice meaning of bound and how that relates to a "function referance" and a "function call". I will update my answer accordingly. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Ok.. so correctly `this` can be said to be `bound` when invoking a function call. For objects `this` is automatic bound when invoking the function, unless the function reference is `bound` to another object. A bound function refers to the method explicitly bound via the `Function.bind()`, or 'this.func = function(){}', or ?? So correctly "bound" should only refer to function references explicitly bound. I hope I have this right?

Comment: Yeah. Basically whenever you know what the value of `this` is, the function is bound.